# Parsing part of xml file in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml file like this:

```
<d-1>
   <zora>05:23</zora>
   <izlSunca>07:07</izlSunca>
   <podne>11:43</podne>
   <ikindija>13:53</ikindija>
   <aksam>16:17</aksam>
   <jacija>17:49</jacija>
</d-1>
<d-2>
   <zora>05:23</zora>
   <izlSunca>07:07</izlSunca>
   <podne>11:43</podne>
   <ikindija>13:54</ikindija>
   <aksam>16:18</aksam>
   <jacija>17:50</jacija>
</d-2>
```

I want to parse only values in tag d-1, how to do that?

I use SAX Parser..

Comment: If you already use the SAXParser, what exactly is your problem? What have you tried? What didn't work? With a SAXParser, you can simply end reading after reaching the closing </d-1> tag...

Comment: I tried to parse, but i get "zora" from the last day "d-30".. Can you explain me how to do that? Im new in this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem..
I edited xml file:

```
<dan value="1">
   <zora>05:23</zora>
   <izlSunca>07:07</izlSunca>
   <podne>11:43</podne>
   <ikindija>13:53</ikindija>
   <aksam>16:17</aksam>
   <jacija>17:49</jacija>
</dan>
```

and ask if value of day == 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

Using Jdom, and assuming you have some root element...

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new  SAXBuilder();
    Document document = (Document)builder.build(new File("somedocument.xml"));

    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    Element d1 = root.getChild("d-1");
    String txt = d1.getChildText("zora");
```